# Statsd installation on Ubuntu 14.04 issue. Unable to start service after installation

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, statsd

I'm a relative newbie to running ubuntu, but I have followed along with Justin Ellingwood's fantastic tutorials for getting graphite and statsd setup to run on Ubuntu 14.04. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I have completed the installation of statsd as per the tute, but I cannot get the service to start! Whenever I run sudo service statsd start it will say it's successful and give it a process number, but then I run a sudo service statsd status command it shows the status statsd stop/waiting. Anyone know what I might be able to do to track this issue down?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You could try asking on [ubuntu.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, after the command

```
sudo dpkg -i statsd*.deb
```

type

```
sudo cp -r ~/build/statsd/servers /usr/share/statsd
```

This solution is explained here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04.